# How do I set a 'placeholder ' value for a Text Field control in XCode

Tags: xcode, macos, controls

I am trying to modify an XCode 12.3 project for MacOS (Catalina) in Objective-C to change the value shown in a text field shown when the project runs. The Placeholder text shown as one of the control properties when clicking on the text field in the interface design screen (shown by clicking on MainMenu.xib) is overwritten by other text, but I am unable to find this text by searching within the project via the XCode Find-> Find In Project.. option. How is this text set and how can I change it?

Comment: The property is [placeholderString](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstextfield/1399391-placeholderstring).

Comment: This property looks as though it is being set in the application, but using Find->Find In Project does not detect any occurrence of strings appearing in text boxes. May these properties be set from a file that is not searched by Find->Find In Project?

Comment: Just found the strings in MainMenu.xib viewed as a text file in the XML tags NSNoSelectionPlaceHolder and NSNullPlaceHolder within the <dictionary key ="options" tag in the <TextField> tag. Can this data be accessed from XCode?

Comment: Select the text field in IB and take a look at the value binding in the Bindings Inspector.

Comment: Yes, there are a number of placeholder fields visible - thanks. They are empty if a placeholder string is set in the File Inspector. It seems that because there are several types of placeholder visible in Bindings Inspector nothing is shown in File Inspector placeholder field if they are different.